# Use Eloquent ORM on my old classes (database tables) without Laravel

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm trying to use Eloquent ORM (without Laravel) and it's working great on tables or classes that I create through eloquent, for example, this :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Modal{
    $protected $fillable = [
      'user_id',
      'name'
    ];

    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

The above is working great when I do create, select, or any other, example :

```
Category::where(['id', $categoryId])->get();
```

but before installing eloquent I used normal MySQL statements and every table I have in my database I have a corresponding class, for example, I have a user table and the corresponding class is like this :

```
class User {
  $private $id;
  $private $userArray;

  public function __construct($id) {
    // construct code here which is basically grabbing all user info from database table
  }

  // rest of functions used in the class
}
```

So I want to use eloquent on the User table instead of normal MySQL statements that I used to use, but it's not working when I do this :

```
User::where(['id', $userId])->get();
```

I tried adding "use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;" and "extends Modal" and the protected variables to the User class (table, timestamp, and primaryKey) but it did not work.

Can you please guide me on how to connect all my old tables and classes to be used by eloquent?

Thanks.

Comment: Follow the conventions. like naming the table `users` and setting `timestamps` columns...

Comment: Thanks for the comment @medilies, can you please explain more an eloquent noob here.

Comment: [1](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions/) + [2](https://xqsit.github.io/laravel-coding-guidelines/docs/naming-conventions/) Laravel and Eloquent does many thinks magically thanks to its conventions. For example if you define a `User` model Eloquent will automatically target the table named `users` when using that model, if the table isn't named `lower cars => pluralised => model name` you have to set a specific property on your model for that. The same for `timestamps` all this is mentionned in the beginning of Eloquent's docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#table-names